# iOS: How to link App Store link that is being developed

Tags: iphone, ios

I am wondering how to link the Apple App Store link in an app that is currently being developed.

For Example...

I am developing an iPhone game that is not approved by Apple yet (so does not have any App Store link obviously).  But in one of my methods I need to use my iTunes app link (to rate my app).

How do others manage to put their app link on their games?  Do they immediately update their game after Apple approves it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have to have an approved app to do this, however you have to have already created the app in iTunes Connect. Once you have done this, Apple supplies you with a "View in App Store" link on the applications page.

[image]

In addition to this, you can use the following link to send the user directly to your app's rating and reviews page in the App Store.

> itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=APPLE_ID

In the above link, replace "APPLE_ID" with the Apple ID of your app. (see screenshot below)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you create a place for your application, and fill the information about your application, it provides you a link. And that link is what you can use in your application, before making it live.